# TypeError: this.x.x is not a function - Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, typeerror

I have have the following service:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import axios, {AxiosResponse} from 'axios';
import {Network} from '@awesome-cordova-plugins/network/ngx';
import {UserParametersService} from '../databaseServices/user.parameters.service';
import {GetUserCredsServiceService} from '../get-user-creds-service.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SyncServicesService {

  constructor(
    protected network: Network,
    protected userParamsService: UserParametersService,
    protected getUserCreds: GetUserCredsServiceService
  ) {
  }

  async syncUserParams(): Promise<AxiosResponse<any> | void> {

    const token: string = await this.getUserCreds.getStoredToken();
    const uuid: string = await this.getUserCreds.getStoredUuid();
    console.log(token);
    console.log(uuid);

    try {

      const data = this.userParamsService.getUserParameters(uuid);

      axios.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
      axios.defaults.headers.post.Authorization = token;
      return axios.post('https://www.enpoint.co.uk/path/sync/syncUserParams.php', {
        data
      }).then((response) => {

        console.log('is done');
      });
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
      console.log('Could not sync user params to master');
    }

    return;
  }


  public syncDataWithMaster() {

  }


}
```

syncUserParams() can be called from any file.

Within user.parameters.service has the following method:

```
   getUserParameters(uuid) {
    return this.dbInstance.executeSql(`SELECT * from ${this.db_table} where uuid = ?`, [uuid])
      .then((res) => {
        if (res.rows.length == 1) {
          console.log(JSON.stringify(res.rows.item(0)));
          return res.rows.item(0);
        }
        return false;
      }).catch(e => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(e));
      });
  }
```

this is called from within the syncUserParams method.
When I call the syncUserParams method I get the following error in the console:

```
TypeError: this.userParamsService.getUserParameters is not a function
```

This error does not occur from other files just from the above service.

I am wondering how to fix this.

Thanks

The following is where syncUserParams is called from updateYourDetails(). I have cut a lot of irrelevant stuff from the below code:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';
import {UserParametersService} from '../../services/databaseServices/user.parameters.service';
import {AuthenticationService} from '../../services/authentication.service';
import {TimezoneCrudService} from '../../services/databaseServices/timezone.crud.service';
import {ModalController, ToastController} from '@ionic/angular';
import {ModalPopupPage} from '../../models/modal-popup/modal-popup.page';
import {CustomTableModelPage} from '../../models/custom-table-model/custom-table-model.page';
import {SyncServicesService} from '../../services/syncService/syncservices.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-accountdetailed',
  templateUrl: './accountdetailed.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./accountdetailed.page.scss'],
})

export class AccountdetailedPage implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    protected route: ActivatedRoute,
    protected userParamService: UserParametersService,
    protected authService: AuthenticationService,
    protected timezoneService: TimezoneCrudService,
    protected modalController: ModalController,
    protected toastController: ToastController,
    protected syncServices: SyncServicesService
  ) {
  }


  async ngOnInit() {

  }




  public async updateYourDetails() {
    console.log(this.item);
    this.userParamService.updateUser(this.item, 'yes');

    this.syncServices.syncUserParams().then(res => {
      console.log('done init');
    });

    const toast = await this.toastController.create({
      message: 'Saved',
      duration: 2000,
      position: 'middle'
    });
    await toast.present();
  }


}
```

Comment: do you have a class extending `SyncServicesService` anywhere? also could you provide the callstack item, where `syncUserParams` is called

Comment: @Andrei nothing else is extending SyncServicesService and I have add the code from where syncUserParams  is called from

Comment: could you try to log `this` to the console before this line, to make sure it is the correct one?

Comment: @Andrei apologies, I am not sure what you mean

Comment: just add `console.log(this)` before  the line with the error, and check what is logs

Comment: @Andrei ah okay. Nothing is outputted to the console. (Android Studio)

Comment: In cases like this, I usually go to the call stack. Also, trouble shooting by putting a break point in the class constructor, and make sure the service you are trying to call is being injected. As far as syntax goes, nothing looks suspect.

Comment: @joshvito So I have tried to create the service: 
 ng generate service services/syncservices

and this implementation works perfect (ie in the root of services dir) 

However if I do:
 ng generate service services/syncServices/syncservices 
Like in the original example then the error in the example occurs 
So it seems like it doesn't like the service in syncServices dir for some reason

Comment: Has the user.parameters.service been registered to the Injector, via a provider declaration or via `@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})`?